# Android scrollview of mixed size image views that fit together like tetris

Tags: android, gridview, size, imageview, scrollview

What I am trying to create is a scrollview of images of all different sizes that fit together perfectly without any obvious rows or columns. each image represents a food and each food has a certain percentage of the votes from all other users . the percentage of votes determines the imageviews size.  Where it gets kinda tricky is I want to make all these different sized image views fit neatly together in a mixed grid map of images. To give you a visualization of what im trying to create imagine something similar to this http://www.todomap.net/ inside a scollview.

I would normally post code of what ive tryed so far, but none of my attempts have even come close. I cant even think of a good set of keywords to search for a example of something similar.

Comment: Maybe go straight to a [canvas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html), or just use a FrameLayout in your scrollview and twiddle with the LayoutParams of your imageviews.

Comment: As @dokkaebi suggested, A Canvas is the best option for you if you're trying to customize your view upto that extent. You're free to implement the drawing however you like

Comment: You can maybe set imageviews size programatically knowing the screen width. I mean, if you want to show 3 pictures in the first line. The first has 200 votes, the second 100 and the last 60. If you're working in a 720 px width display you can assign 400 px to the first, 200 to the second and 120 to the last. Take a look at Display.getWitdh(), and LayoutParams to achieve this.

Comment: I just had a idea, is it possible to do this in a webview while making each box a link that opens a new activity?

Comment: A webview is possible, but be forewarned: WebView implementations differ a lot across devices and platform versions, and doing anything fancy can be really frustrating. Also watch out for the difference between device pixels and webview pixels; you'll need to do conversions to size things precisely. Also, it is just as easy to launch an activity in a click handler in any other view as it is to do it from a link click in a webview (probably easier, actually).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a gridlayout. You can add views with row span and column span as you desire. And you would get the exact replica of the image of the website you were referring to.

Just extend gridLayout. Use the following functions

```
private Spec getSpan(int span) {
    return spec(UNDEFINED, span, FILL);
}
```

And

```
public void addView(View view, int row_span, int column_span) {
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(getSpan(row_span), getSpan(column_span));
    params.height = square_height*row_span;
    params.width = square_width*column_span;
    addView(view, params);
}
```

Then you can add views to the gridlayout, and it will find the best locations for them.
Remember to define ***rows, columns, square_width and square_height***.

```
setRowCount(rows);
setColumnCount(columns);
```